# Unable to view item in browser based on its key in Python GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

I'm using python GAE with webapp.

I have a form for a user to create a object in the database, something like:

```
class SpamRecord(db.Model):
    author = db.ReferenceProperty(Author, required=True)
    text = db.StringProperty()
```

After it's created, the user is redirected to a page whose URL contains that object's key... using code such as:

```
spam = SpamRecord(author=author, text=text)
spam.put()
new_spam_key = spam.key()
self.redirect("/view_spam/%s" % new_spam_key)
```

And this *mostly* works, with me being able to view items at:

> sitename.com/view_spam/ag1waWNreXByZXNlbnRzchQLEgxBbm5vdW5jZW1lbnQYy8oJDA
>   sitename.com/view_spam/ag1waWNreXByZXNlbnRzchQLEgxBbm5vdW5jZW1lbnQY_boJDA

However, there's an occasional key that won't work.  Here are 2 recent examples of pages that won't load and return `HTTP 404 not found` errors:

> sitename.com/view_spam/ag1waWNreXByZXNlbnRzchQLEgxBbm5vdW5jZW1lbnQY-5MJDA
>   sitename.com/view_spam/ag1waWNreXByZXNlbnRzchQLEgxBbm5vdW5jZW1lbnQY-boJDA

My `html-mappings.py` contains the following mapping:

```
(r"/view_spam/(\w+)", ViewSpamPage)
```

And the `ViewSpamPage` looks something like:

```
class ViewSpamPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, spam_id):
        self.response.out.write("Got here")
```

Can anyone offer any insight as to why this is occurring and how it may be prevented?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In regular expressions, `\w` doesn't match hyphens. (It will match underscores.) For that second pair of keys, this'll result in only passing *part* of the key to your handler.

In your URL pattern, try `r"/view_spam/(.*)"` instead.